# XML Issue: Content type 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: java, xml, post

Hello I am currently writing code in java to send a post xml request to a url

```
response = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().request().contentType("text/xml").body(new String(readFileContent(fileName, folderName, jsonObj, "xml", csvData))).when().post(url);
```

However when my code trys to run the code i get back a:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

What could be the reason's that I can debug through to find out what the issue is?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: instead of text/xml, try to use application/xml charset=utf-8 as content type.

Comment: My first reaction to this is that the service being called was written by someone who doesn’t know what they’re doing.  There is absolutely no reason to require a particular encoding for XML content.